Meaning of "rankear" - ¿Qué significa "rankear"?
En la descripción de este canal en YouTube, el youtuber incluyó esta frase "Hoy rankearemos canciones de sonic en directo". Por supuesto tiene sentido que "rankear" signifique "to rank", pero cuando busqué "rankear" en SpanishDictionary.com, no hay ningún resultado. Esta palabra es similar a otros verbos modernos como "textear" ("to text")?
In the description of this YouTube channel, the YouTuber included this phrase "Hoy rankearemos canciones de sonic en directo". Of course it makes sense that "rankear" means "to rank", but when I searched for "rankear" in SpanishDictionary.com, there are no results. This word is similar to other modern verbs like textar "to text" maybe?

Pregunta: ¿Qué significa "rankear"?
Respuesta: Significa clasificar.
to rank someone in a list for some purpose, in Spanish =
clasificar
to rank football players [soccer]
primer equipo-clasificación [ranking]
clasificar los futbolistas.
Eso de rankear es spanglish o un americanismo porque el español dispone de la palabra perfecta: clasificar.
Por ejemplo: clasificar

Clasificación del Deportista y Programación del Entrenamiento=

Ranking of players and training scheduling

RAE @RAEinforma
#RAEconsultas «Situarse(se) en una tabla o escalafón» o «clasificarse». En América se documentan «ranquear» y «rankear», por
influencia del inglés. 8:58 AM · Apr 19, 2018

en X

Lo más común es escribir ranquear, con q.

Clasificar algo o a alguien, especialmente a un deportista, en un escalafón según su rendimiento.

Literalmente, rank en inglés.
En Spanish Dict aparece solo con q por lo que veo.
No obstante, en el Damer y en el diccionario de la Fundación BBVA aparece también la variante con k.
Como side note, deberías tener sumo cuidado al buscar palabras en sitios como Spanish Dicitonary, Linguee, Reverso, etc., sobre todo cuando se trata de traducciones hechas por IAs que todavía ni siquiera fueron revisadas por personas. De todas formas en general lo bueno es que esos sitios dejan marcado cuando la traducción se generó automáticamente y todavía no fue revisada.

@Sofronias alguien que maneja el idioma ni siquiera necesita de un diccionario.

Gracias para su side note @tac. Me recomiendas que uso asale.org  para aprendar palabaras que parece como americanismos en lugar de spanishdict.com, que piense?

asale.org/damer es un buen lugar para comenzar. En es.wiktionary.org también hay varias palabras que no figuran en el Damer. Si están revisados por personas en lugar de generados por IA mejor. Saludos.

El significado en el ejemplo citado sería "determinar o calcular el ranking de algo".
Otro significado de "rankear", similar pero diferente, es "posicionarse, figurar (en un ranking)".
Un ejemplo:

¿Cómo rankea Argentina entre los países con mejor calidad de vida en el mundo?

Ambos significados están importados del inglés "to rank", supongo.

Es una errata: la palabra correcta es renquear, y el significado que aplica es el de la segunda acepción: "Tener dificultad en alguna empresa, negocio, quehacer, etc.".
El autor de la frase quiere decir que va a revisar  canciones con las que tiene dificultades.
